# Dialog box doesn't show when calling on external js file

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm having a problem accessing my dialog box when I try calling it on external js file, but when I call it directly inside the page it works fine. Is there a problem with my selector that it cannot find the id of the div element which is suppose to be my dialog box? here' the code inside the external js file.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
       var hitlistDoc = parent.document.getElementById("hitlist").contentDocument;
       var links=hitlistDoc.getElementsByName('linkComment');
       var i=0;


       $(links).each(function(){
             links[i].href='#';

              $(links[i]).click(function() {

                    $('#dialog').dialog({modal: true, position: [902, 345], width: 400 });
                   $('#dialog').dialog('open');

               });
           i++;     
        });

    });
```

Comment: Could be the order you're loading the scripts in. Is jQuery & jQuery UI loaded before your external one?

Comment: Yes I follow the order. The order is include/jquery-ui.css,include/jquery-1.6.1.js,include/jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.min.js and then include/js/util.js

Answer (score 0):

You may be including it wrong. Your js inclusion should be like this

```
<script src="path/to/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="path/to/jqueryUI.js"></script>
<script src="path/to/your/external/file.js"></script>
```

Note that the order is crucial.

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: 'code'<link href="assets/css/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script  src="include/js/jquery-1.6.1.js"></script>
<script  src="include/js/jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type ="text/javascript" src="include/js/util.js"></script>                                                            Scanning the codes I'm sure I follow the order.

Answer (score 0):

What is parent? Is it accessible?
If it's declared as a var within another anonymous function you can't access it, try taking off "var" to make it global.

Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: Yes its accessible, in fact If I omit the dialog part and replace it with alert box it actually pop when I click the link.

Comment: I just want to clarify, the parent is a frame then the src is the page to be loaded. <frame src='hitlist2.asp' id='hitlist'....> ,I put a button inside hitlist2.asp page and put this $('#buttonsample').val('change if link click') inside the script above and as I click the link the button change its value so I think I'm sure I can access the element by id inside that page, I'm just wondering why if I called the dialog command nothing happens and no dialog box popup.